# How to pass input props to a component inside a component in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm learning react and typescript and i'm building a form using styled components.

I want to pass props like onChange, type and value to my `<Ìnput />` component but i dont know how to do this.

I have a `<FormData />` page component were i use my `<Ìnput />` component like this:

```
import { Container } from './styles';

import Header from '../../components/Header';
import Input from '../../components/Input';

const FormData: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Container>

      <Header>Your Data</Header>

      <fieldset>
        <legend>Personal Info</legend>
        <Input label='Nome' placeholder='Duck ' onChange={ () => {} } />
        {...others inputs here}
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset>
        <legend>Profissional Info</legend>
        <Input label='curriculum' placeholder='123.412.123-44' type={textarea}/>
      </fieldset>

    </Container>
  );
};

export default FormData;
```

and my `<Ìnput />` component looks like this:

```
import { Label, InputField } from './styles';

interface InputProps {
  label: string;
  placeholder?: string;
}

function Input({ label, placeholder }: InputProps) {
  return (
    <Label>
      {label}
      <InputField placeholder={placeholder} />
    </Label>
  );
}

export default Input;
```

I tried to ref and forwardRef and then pass it on props to my  styled component but it didnt work.

In my `<InputField />` styled component i would like to pass onChange, value and type props received on my generic `<Input />` used on `<FormData />`

And inside my `<InputField />` styled component i would like to do something like this:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const { type } = this.props // Can i do that?

export const InputField = styled.type`
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0.3rem;
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. use an `input` markup for the `InputField` styled component :

```
export const InputField = styled.input`
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0.3rem;
`;
```

2. simply use it as a normal input in your code :

```
function Input({ label, placeholder, handleChange }: InputProps) {
  return (
    <Label>
      {label}
      <InputField type="text" onChange={handleChange} placeholder={placeholder} />
    </Label>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Emmanuel, but i would like to create a generic input, thats why i need somehow a ```type``` prop to use it like InputField = styled.type` {css} `

Comment: ah ok, how about using the `as` prop from styled component ? `<InputField as={"someType"} /> ?

Comment: Thanks @Emmanuel, i tried it but i dont know how to fix typescript "as" error type. and i couldnt use handleChange prop inside <Input handleChange{() => {} } /> component, even setting handleChange as Function type on component input types Props.

Comment: It's `<InputField as={type} onChange={...} />`, maybe you could update your question with 
 your code and the typescript error message ? that will be easier to help out : )